# XCode reports no launch images specified after localization and can't add them

Tags: ios, xcode

I had a set of launch images specified in XCode (5.0) in the general section. But then after localizing the images XCode has started to say there is no image specified, and if I try to add one nothing happens.

What I did was:

1. Add the various image sizes to the Xcode Target general section
2. Select the image in the navigator and from the inspector choose to localize it
3. This created an English variant.
4. Select it again in the navigator and add a language (Spanish)
5. Now there is en.lproj and es.lproj folders which XCode created
6. The images in the es.lproj at this point are duplicates of those on the en.lproj so I dragged and dropped new Spanish versions into es.lproj to replace the English one.
7. Some hours later I noticed XCode now says there is no launch images specified
8. If I try to select an image, for example one in en.lproj then nothing happens and XCode still reports no images specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can get an idea to your answer here in this post of [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709151/1307844).

Please do check the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567865/1307844). That is more close to your question.