# IOS: multiple language xcode 5 for launch image

Tags: ios, localization, xcode5, splash-screen, launchimage

I have a problem, what's the way to organize localized launch images in xcode 5, is there a way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!!**

Set in plist file "Launch image" in "Default"

and have two file for launch image in the project as

```
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad and Default-Landscape@~ipad
```

that you can localize as another file...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a way to do that. Looks like you can get an idea to your answer here in this post of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706851/i-added-a-localization-in-xcode-removed-it-and-now-my-storyboard-is-gone/15709151#15709151) Question.

Please do check the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314655/xcode-load-localized-images-with-the-same-name-not-using-nslozalicedstring/4567865#4567865). That is more close to your question.

Comment: Link to an answer, which is just a link to another answer?

Comment: Yes, so that you can see even other's questions with similar problem, while traversing back to the actual answer.

Comment: Not correct. Post a comment containing the link and then flag the question as duplicate. Otherwise SO will start to look messy with everyone asking the same questions and linking everything to each other. It's sloppy.

Comment: @CaptJak : I have edited the answer as advised. Hope this will not make things messy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create a temp `ViewController` and you can put a `UIImageView` on your `View`. After launch your program you can direct to this temp `ViewController` and set the image according to your language. than you can call your main `ViewController`.

And i used this class for change the language in my program.
https://github.com/tonisalae/TSLanguageManager

I hope, it can be help for you.

Comment: This is more like a splash screen. But launch image is something that renders on on the full screen on device before you load any of your view controller. You will still see the default black screen for a moment untill your app finished the loading of your tempviewController

Comment: Yes i know, but the user will wait only more 1-2 secs, and will not understand.I used to this one before and i didn't get any complaints.

Comment: It's not about getting complain from users. The real goal of launch image is to provide user a fast responsive feel. However it's just an impression. Refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html) in documentation.

Comment: Yes you right but, we can't set the image to launch image dynamically , so i just adviced that way :).